# Query to find the different email address series

Tags: sql-server

I need some help on the problem below-

I want to find the series of different email addresses from the database table using SQL query.

My database table contains email addresses -

```
abc1@..com,
abc2@..com,
.
.
.
.
f1@..com,
f2@..com,
f3@..com
.
.
.
xyzpqr1@..com,
xyzpqr2@..com
.
.
```

These email series patterns are always different but they shares the common series pattern like numbers say 1 to 10 e.g. `pq1@..com,pq2@..com,pq3@..com,...,pq10@..com,,,`
where text "pq" could be anything which is a random text. And also numbers (1 to 10 in above case) are also random.

We can detect this series by copying the data in excel and then manually checking the each records. But this is not the feasible solution

So I was thinking that can someone come up with the SQL query which would be helpful to detect such series of email addresses.

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012...The data is large so can't pass it.. hope you guys got my question to find the different series of email addresses as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: I mean sample data is there in my question itself..anyway here it is

Comment: pq1@one.com
pq2@one.com
pq3@one.com
pq4@one.com
pq5@one.com
pq6@one.com
pq7@one.com
pq8@one.com
pq9@one.com
pq10@one.com

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Just replace all numeric characters and apply `RANK` window function. `rank` column will group your emails:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( email NVARCHAR(MAX) )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'some1@gmail.com' ),
        ( 'some2@gmail.com' ),
        ( 'some3@gmail.com' ),
        ( 'someother1@gmail.com' ),
        ( 'someother2@gmail.com' );

WITH    cte1
          AS ( SELECT   email ,
                        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(email,
                                                              '1', ''), '2',
                                                              ''), '3', ''),
                                                              '4', ''), '5',
                                                              ''), '6', ''),
                                                        '7', ''), '8', ''),
                                        '9', ''), '0', '') AS newemail
               FROM     @t
             ),
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY newemail ) AS rank
               FROM     cte1
             )
    SELECT  * FROM    cte2
```

Output:

```
email                  newemail             rank
some1@gmail.com        some@gmail.com       1
some2@gmail.com        some@gmail.com       1
some3@gmail.com        some@gmail.com       1
someother1@gmail.com   someother@gmail.com  4
someother2@gmail.com   someother@gmail.com  4
```